# bootstrap carousel auto sliding when window is not active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is the website i'm working on. The problem is even tough i used interval:false and pause:true, whenever i inspect the code or switch to another the main slider starts auto-sliding. How can i stop it for good?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.carousel').carousel({
        pause: true,
        interval: false
    });
```

This is the javascript concerning the said item.

Comment: You want to pause the carousel when window is not active?

Comment: i want the default state of the carousel to be paused, no matter what

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to remove `data-ride="carousel"` from the carousel HTML container and only use `class="carousel"`

then use `interval: false` only you don't need to use pause option

```
$(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
       interval: false
    });
});
```

Comment: that does indeed solve the problem, however it disables the sliding effect to say so. can't i keep it pretty? :(

Comment: @morgred add slide to the class. class="carousel slide"